# How to check working internet present in Android Device?

Tags: android, android-networking

Am checking internet present or not by following method.

```
public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        return (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    } else
        return false;}
```

But when connected to wifi,but no working internet is there then also this method gives true.

Thanks in advance, please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be help you

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public static boolean Check_Internet_Connectivity(Context _context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(_context, "Internet Connection is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `obj.isAvailable()` to check network availability.

You can find More Here
[NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is how internet is checked:-

100% working code

```
private AlertDialog internetDialog, gpsAlertDialog;
  public BroadcastReceiver internetConnectionReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                NetworkInfo activeWIFIInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getNetworkInfo(connectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                if (activeWIFIInfo.isConnected() || activeNetInfo.isConnected()) {
                    removeInternetDialog();
                } else {
                    if (isNetDialogShowing) {
                        return;
                    }
                    showInternetDialog();
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping any real host (sample 8.8.8.8)

```java
InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").isReachable(timeOut)
```

Comment: Ping does not support some devices

Answer (score -1):

if you happen to loading page by webview , you can check it also for calling for custom 404 error page :

```
webView.loadUrl(urlhere);    
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new404.html");

                }
            });
```

Comment: i am just trying to help, by checking the error if using webview you know the internet is not active. , i hope the one who downvote me got bad day.